# Sweet Alert Form Submit Confirmation Doesn't Submit the Form

Tags: sweetalert2

I'm using Sweet Alert to confirm the intent to delete records with the code below.  I get the Sweet Alert Pop up, click OK...but the form never submits. I get the alert ('ok) (commented out in the code) but form.submit() does nothing.  I've looked online for a solution but I mostly find form.submit() as the answer.  Is there a way to get this working?

```
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>

<form method="post" action=""   onsubmit="return submitForm(this);">
    <input type="hidden" name="delete_data" value="10"> 
     <input type="submit"  name="submit-survey" id="submit" value="Clear Data"> 
</form> 

<script>
    function submitForm(form) {
        new swal({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            text: "This will clear the data",
            icon: "warning",
            buttons: true,
            dangerMode: true,
        })
        .then(function (isOkay) {
            if (isOkay) {
                //alert('ok')
                //return true;
                form.submit();
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the only way I've found that works..and it requires two forms since it appears you can't do this with one form.

```
$(function(){
    
    $("#from1").submit(function(e){
        event.preventDefault();
        let flag = $('#from1').attr('data-flag');
        if(flag == 0){
            Swal.fire({
                title: 'Are you sure?',
                text: "Do you want to clear out the submissions?",
                type: "warning",
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: '#DD6B55',
                confirmButtonText: 'Yes, I am sure!',
                cancelButtonText: "No, cancel it!",
                closeOnConfirm: false,
                closeOnCancel: false
            }).then((result) => {
                if (result.isConfirmed) {
                    $('#from1').attr('data-flag', '1');
                    $('#from2').submit();
                } else {
                    Swal.fire("Cancelled", "Submission clearance cancelled", "error");
                }
            })
        }
    });
```

and then the two forms

```
<form id="from2" action="" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="clear_subs">
</form>



<form id="from1" data-flag="0" action="" method="POST">
  Clear Submissions  <input type="submit" id="checkbox" >

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you've got a `onsubmit="submitForm(this);"` action, but then you're later calling `form.submit()` so it probably just repeats that same action every time. Checking the console with those `console.log` lines should confirm this by clicking the "Yes I'm sure!" button multiple times.

Instead of mixing the two, I'd recommend triggering something on the button's click to make the swal pop up, then if the result is confirmed call `form.submit()` from there.

Comment: Ok..I tried adding document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function() {   instead of the function submitForm(form).  The submit successfully fires the swal pop up, but when click ok, nothing happens.

Comment: @Allen I played with this a bit with a jsFiddle and was seeing console errors with using a `submit` call on a form directly. Is this intentionally posting to the same page it's running on? Any reason it can't be an AJAX call?

Comment: It was supposed to post to the same page. I was trying to do this without an AJAX call.  As I said in the original post, many people said you could do this directly to whatever page you want to process the info. But I can’t make it work.